# Merge a Specific sheet from multi excel files into a new file

Tags: excel, vba, file, merge

I need your help to improve the code.
I have multi excel files ( 300 files) with the same format in one folder. I want to merge only the sheet name (DATA) from each excel in the folder. and I want to list the names of merged files in seperte sheet.

I am new to VBA. I have tried many solutions provided in this website, but I don't get the desired result. your help is appreciated

here is my try

```
Sub openfiles()
'declare the variables used within the VBA code
Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String, wbmain As Workbook, lastrow As Long
'disable these functions to enhance code processing
With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With
'change the path of the folder where your files are going to be saved
MyFolder = InputBox("Enter path of the Merge folder") & "\"
'define the reference of the folder in a macro variable
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder)
'open a loop to cycle through each individual workbook stored in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
'activate the Merge workbook
Windows("Merge").Activate
'calculate the last populated row
Range("a1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
'open the first workbook within the Merge folder
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile
Windows(MyFile).Activate
'toggle through each sheet within the workbooks to copy the data
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Activate
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
'ignore the header and copy the data from row 2
If Cells(2, 1) = "" Then GoTo 1
GoTo 10
1: Next
10: Range("a2:u200").Copy

Windows("Merge").Activate
'paste the copied contents
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows(MyFile).Activate
'close the open workbook once the data is pasted
ActiveWorkbook.Close
'empty the cache to store the value of the next workbook
MyFile = Dir()
'open the next file in the folder
Loop
'enable the disabled functions for future use

With Application
.DisplayAlerts = True
.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to merge only sheet DATA from the opened workbook, then you don't need to loop to each sheet ---> `For Each ws In Sheets` ---> no need. Maybe try to directly check, something like this : `with sheets("DATA"): .autofiltermode=false: if .range("A2").value <> "" then range("a2:u200").copy destination:=workbooks("blablabla").sheets("Merge").range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1,0)): end with`.

Comment: Suppose you have two files and each one has a DATA sheet and they have the values (A1=10, B1=20 A2=11, B2=22 ) and (A1=100, B1=200 A2=110, B2=220 ) What are you waiting for to appear in the new file?

Comment: this can be done with powerquery, there are many tutorials on youtube

Comment: @karma I want sheet "Data" from 300 files in a folder and not oppened

Comment: @wmb8084, oops sorry... because I see in your code `Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile`, so I thought that you want to open it.